# ¿Como puedo volcar una relación de sql a eloquent?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Buenos días quería saber como hacer la siguiente relación sql:

Tabla clientes:

```
id PRIMARY KEY auto increment,
company varchar(45) not null,
holding varchar (45) not null,
id_holding int not null
```

Cabe aclarar que esta tabla no la cree en mysql ni sqlserver ni otro, solamente la realicé acá para que se pueda entender la pregunta, asi que puede que la tabla tenga algún error.

Mi idea es que la tabla contenga jerarquía en si misma, es decir

```
---------------------------------------------------
| id          |   company  |  id_holding| holding  |
 --------------------------------------------------
|       1     |    Disney  |      0     |Disney    | 
|       2     |    Espn    |      1     |Disney    |
|       3     |    Fox     |      1     |Disney    |
|       4     |  Fox sports|      3     |Fox       |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Esta tabla muestra que disney no tiene una compañia padra o jefe si no que el holding es la compañia misma. Pero en el caso de Espn y Fox que pertenecen a Disney llevan como holding a Disney y por ende el id del holding es el id de disney. Y por ultimo tenemos a Fox sports que por mas que Fox pertenezca a Disney, tambien puede tener una compañia como subordinada. Espero que se pueda entender el ejemplo de manera correcta

Ahora yo tengo mi modelo Customer donde quiero realizar esta relación pero no logro entender como hacerlo:

```php
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'holding',
        'company',
        'legal_entity',
        'mobile_no',
        'email',
        'country',
        'state',
        'city',
        'address',
        'postal',
        'cuit',
        'website',
        'status'
    ];
```

Y este es mi metodo store de la migration create_customers_table:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('holding');
        $table->string('company')->nullable();
        $table->string('legal_entity')->nullable();
        /*$table->string('mobile_no');
        $table->string('mobile_two')->nullable();
        $table->string('mobile_three')->nullable();*/
        $table->string('email');
        /*$table->string('position')->nullable();*/
        $table->string('country')->nullable();
        $table->string('state')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->string('address')->nullable();
        $table->string('postal')->nullable();
        $table->string('cuit');
        $table->string('website')->nullable();
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default('1');
        $table->integer('id_parentCompany')->nullable();
        $table->integer('created_by')->nullable();
        $table->integer('updated_by')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Pero como pueden ver al id_parentCompany que sería el id del holding le puse nullable porque no sabía como hacer para que me cargue en el registro el id del holding.

Comment: Pero que quieres hacer

Comment: Tal vez este paquete te sirva: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list

Answer (score 0):

Simplificando, si entendí tu pregunta necesitas es una tabla "customers" y una tabla "companies" donde en la segunda existe una "relación reflexiva", es decir una o varias compañías pueden tener una compañía "padre".

Creo dos modelos, migraciones y seeders con los comandos:

```
php artisan make:model Company -ms
php artisan make:model Customer -ms
```

*Es importante crear primero la tabla de compañías, por las FKs que añadiré en cada migración.*

En cuanto a las relaciones, una compañía puede tener muchos clientes y a su vez una, varias o ninguna compañía asociada. Entonces el esquema ER:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Nota**. Voy a usar **Laravel7** para las pruebas, la sintaxis de las migraciones creo que no cambia, pero los seeders en **Laravel8** llevan namespaces. Además, los modelos en **Laravel8** van en la carpeta Models de app.*

Las migraciones (en clientes pondré lo mínimo para el ejemplo):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCustomersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name', 150);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('company_id');

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('company_id', 'customers_to_companies_fk')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('companies');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('customers');
    }
}


<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCompaniesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('company', 150);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('holding_id')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('holding_id', 'companies_to_companies_fk')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('companies');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('companies');
    }
}
```

En cuando a los seeders:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(CompanySeeder::class);
        $this->call(CustomerSeeder::class);
    }
}

<?php

use App\Company;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CompanySeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $company = new Company();
        $company->company = 'Disney';
        $company->save();

        $company = new Company();
        $company->company = 'Espn';
        $company->holding_id = Company::whereCompany('Disney')->first()->id;
        $company->save();

        $company = new Company();
        $company->company = 'Fox';
        $company->holding_id = Company::whereCompany('Disney')->first()->id;
        $company->save();

        $company = new Company();
        $company->company = 'Fox Sports';
        $company->holding_id = Company::whereCompany('Fox')->first()->id;
        $company->save();
    }
}

<?php

use App\Customer;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CustomerSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->name = 'Foo';
        $customer->company_id = 1;
        $customer->save();

        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->name = 'Baz';
        $customer->company_id = 1;
        $customer->save();
    }
}
```

Los modelos:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo as BelongsToCollection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany as HasManyCollection;

class Company extends Model
{

    public function children(): HasManyCollection
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Company::class, 'holding_id');
    }

    public function customers(): HasManyCollection
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
    }

    public function holding(): BelongsToCollection
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'holding_id');
    }
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo as BelongsToCollection;

class Customer extends Model
{

    public function holding(): BelongsToCollection
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Y unas pruebas.
Yo usé **tinker**:

```
php artisan tinker
```

Obtener la primera compañía y la primera con holding:

```
$firstCompany = Company::first();
$firstCompanyWithHolding = Company::where('holding_id', '!=', null)->first();
```

Como disney tiene varios "hijos", puedo verlos con:

```
$firstCompany->children;
```

Veras que aparecen sus dos hijos.

No tiene holding, entonces lo siguiente devuelve `null`:

```
$firstCompany->holding;
```

Y finalmente:

```
$firstCompanyWithHolding->holding;
```